# using Directory with timer corona sdk

Tags: timer, lua, sdk, coronasdk

I'm trying to use the directory with  the "Recipes" example..
I have a problem with the timer

after I run the `main.lua` page
it should show my logo and welcome massage then , it should go to intro page
where I have a screen to get the user name and mobile only when he use the application for first time and save it into txt file , then next time it will check that txt file..

next , it will direct to "Menu" page where user can Select from

my problem that in the `main.lua` I use timer to show the logo, but this timer still work in other screens .

```
Main.lua (cdoe)

_w = display.viewableContentWidth
_h = display.viewableContentHeight

 local background = display.newRect(0,0,_w,_h)
 background:setFillColor( 234, 234, 234 ) 

local obj = display.newImage( "ams_logo.jpg" )

-- center the object
obj.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
obj.y = display.contentHeight*0.5

-- fade object to completely transparent
local transition_id = transition.from( obj, { time=2000, alpha=0 } )

--local textObject = display.newText( "Welcome to AMS project", 20, 350, native.systemFont, 24 )
local textObject = display.newText( "Welcome to AMS project", _w*.1, _h*.8, native.systemFont, 24 )
textObject:setTextColor( 255,144,0 )
local transition_id = transition.from( textObject, { time=1500, alpha=0 })

function changeScene (e)
    if(e.phase == "ended") then
        director:changeScene(e.target.scene)
    end

end

local director = require("director");
local mainGroup = display.newGroup();

mainGroup:insert(director.directorView);
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar) _W = display.contentWidth _H = display.contentHeight number = 0

function fn_counter()

director:changeScene("intro");

end
timer.performWithDelay(5500, fn_counter, 0)


the intro .lua 

    module(..., package.seeall)

function new()

    local introGroup = display.newGroup();

        local background = display.newImage("graphics/intro_background.png")

        local begin = display.newImage("graphics/begin_button.png")
        begin.x = 160; 
        begin.y = 400;
        begin.scene = "menu";

        introGroup:insert(background);
        introGroup:insert(begin);

        begin:addEventListener("touch", changeScene);


    return introGroup;

end
```

please help me ..

Answer (score 1):

In the function

```
timer.performWithDelay( 5500, fn_counter, 0 )
```

means, call fn_counter() in every 5500 seconds and do it infinitely many times ( beacause of 0 argument ). You should change that as

```
timer.performWithDelay( 5500, fn_counter, 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to make a delay? 
...if so you can use lua's os.execute function like

```
function delay(s)--this is what i use for OS X and it works fine
os.execute("sleep "..s)
end
```

if you are having a target os client you can use it's command window like windows's cmd or OS X's termanal. and i understand that corona works with those os.also i apologize that i might not be as much help, your question was not very specific to me.